# What is the appropriate driver to load for embedded DynamoDB in a Spring app?

Tags: spring, configuration, amazon-dynamodb

I followed various tutorials to end up with the configuration below. There may also be incorrect configuration causing the problem. When I run the tests, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "test" are currently active).
```

Research has lead me to believe that the appropriate driver is not being loaded and I have to add it to `.properties`.  Is that something included in DynamoDBLocal library? I can't find it in the docs and it seems my only option is to get a 3rd party driver from the web.

Here's are the important parts:

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

DataSourceConfigLocal:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages="com.cfa.dao")
@Profile({"local", "test"})
public class DataSourceConfigLocal {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB
                = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(amazonAWSCredentials());

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint)) {
            amazonDynamoDB.setEndpoint(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint);
        }

        return amazonDynamoDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(
                amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);
    }
}
```

IntegrationTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Profile("test")
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://localhost:8000/",
        "amazon.aws.accesskey=x",
        "amazon.aws.secretkey=x" })
public class OrderRequestRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;

    @Autowired
    OrderRequestDao orderRequestDao;

    private static final String STORE_NUMBER = "100";

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);

        CreateTableRequest tableRequest = dynamoDBMapper
                .generateCreateTableRequest(OrderRequest.class);
        tableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(
                new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));
        amazonDynamoDB.createTable(tableRequest);

        dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(
                (List<OrderRequest>)orderRequestDao.findAll());
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTestCase() {
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest(STORE_NUMBER);
        orderRequestDao.save(orderRequest);

        List<OrderRequest> result
                = (List<OrderRequest>) orderRequestDao.findAll();

        assertTrue("Not empty", result.size() > 0);
        assertTrue("Contains item with expected cost",
                result.get(0).getStoreNumber().equals(STORE_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you have already referred this. I am adding this as it may help you.

[Test using HTTP and without using HTTP](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/DynamoDBLocalFixture.java)

[pom file which has the server runner and sql lite](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/pom.xml)

1) Also, use the latest version **`1.11.0.1`** of the JAR.

2) SQL Lite lib in classpath

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
    <version>${aws.dynamodblocal.version}</version>
</dependency>

<profile>
            <id>start-dynamodb-local</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>java</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-cp</argument>
                                        <classpath/>
                                        <argument>-Dsqlite4java.library.path=${basedir}/target/dependencies</argument>
                                        <argument>com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner</argument>
                                        <argument>-inMemory</argument>
                                        <argument>-port</argument>
                                        <argument>${dynamodb-local.port}</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is meant to address the problem I'm having.